# RewriteRule: bad flag delimiters after migrating WordPress site

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I migrated a previous site which was partly broken and resulting 403 forbidden error on the browser. I migrated the site under a new domain name and the site shows this error message:

[image: Error message]

The error message that I get in my error log is:

```
[Sun Oct 01 13:46:24.974016 2017] [core:alert] [pid 313593:tid 140292694972160] [client 66.249.82.216:55940] /home/orunodoi/public_html/viralyield.com/.htaccess: RewriteRule: bad flag delimiters
```

The .htaccess of the site is:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# uploaded files
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?files/(.+) wp-includes/ms-files.php?file=$2 [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^[_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $1 [L]
RewriteRule ^[_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/(.*\.php)$ $1 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
# END WordPress
```

I don't know why the error occurs. The hosting provider confirmed that there is some coding issues. But from my end I didn't make any coding change. Yes, I uploaded a HTML document and a table on the database and after that the error occurs. Please help.

Comment: There seems to be no syntax Error, and the only Flag that I see is [L],[R] and [OR] and this is ok. There is also no space in [R=301,L] or in any other flag. I tested your .htaccess on my server and did not receive this error so I believe this is not because of your .htaccess file itself. Maybe some other server configuration problem. What I would do is adding only one line after each other and see on what line the error comes back.

Comment: It's also possible you have some "funny" characters in your source file (which may have been santized out when pasting into the StackOverflow editor) that are causing this error. If this is the case, then copying the code back into your original file, might help. (However, I would have expected a 500 error response returned to the browser if this was the error, not a "time out"?)